# Error while installing Egit in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hello while installing Egit in eclipse i am getting the below error.Can any one please help?

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider - Task focused interface 3.6.1.201501031845-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 3.6.1.201501031845-r)
>     Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.6.1.201501031845-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.6.1.201501031845-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Git Team Provider - Task focused interface 3.6.1.201501031845-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 3.6.1.201501031845-r)
>       To: org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you seems to have an old Eclipse version. According to the [EGit FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F), they are supporting about two versions backwards. Version 3.6.1 (the one you are installing) seems to require Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno release train); if you have an older Eclipse version of Eclipse, it is the issue. Check the table in the FAQ for the latest version you can use.